# Why doesn't python find the correct root path?

Tags: python

I git cloned a project from remote git repository into a temporary directory:

```
/data3/min/temp/kbmb/
```

I created a virtual environment 'my-env' and installed it in this environment. There is a test file in this project so I ran it under kbmb/:

```
python nlu/tests/random_test.py
```

It reported an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nlu/tests/random_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nlu
  File "/data3/min/kbmb/nlu/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  ...
```

This part of the error is that it didn't find the correct root:

```
/data3/min/kbmb/
```

As you can see, the 'temp' directory is missing from the path in the error message. I cloned the project into the temp directory and everything should be in the temp/ directory.

What might cause this?

Comment: Git is not relevant here: only Python's search path (`$PYTHONPATH`, `sys.path`, etc) matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in your script "nlu/tests/random_test.py" the first line is trying to `import nlu`

If you include this **before** the `import nlu`:

```
import sys
sys.paht.append('/data3/min/temp/kbmb/')
```

then the `import nlu` line should work.

Comment: But i shouldn't hard code this path, right? 'nlu' is already installed into my environment by 'pip install nlu'

Comment: Yes better not to hardcore... If nlu it is "installed" then you should be able to import it... Try to load your environment and then to open a python shell. And try the import there... Make sure you have your virtualenv activated

Comment: I reactivated my virtual environment and it worked. Thanks.